# Setting initial value of TextField from Flow in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a TextField component that I want to set the initial content to. The initial content will be fetched from a database using a Flow.

I have this `TextField` code (loosely following [this codelabs tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state#5)):

```
@Composable
private fun EntryText(placeholder: String, initialText: String = "", ) {
    val (text, setText) = remember { mutableStateOf(initialText) }
    EntryTextField(
        text = text,
        placeholder = placeholder,
        onTextChanged = setText
    )
}
```

and

```
@Composable
private fun EntryTextField(text: String, placeholder: String, onTextChanged: (String) -> Unit) {
    TextField(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {
            onTextChanged(it)
        },
        placeholder = { Text(text = placeholder) }
    )
}
```

I want use it like so to set both a `Text` and the content of the `EntryText`:

```
val entry by viewModel.getEntryContent().collectAsState(initial = "initial")
val hint = "hint"
Column {
        Text(text = entry)
        EntryText(placeholder = hint, initialText = entry)
}
```

When the ViewModel `getEntryContent` flow emits the result from the database only the `Text` is being updated with the new String and not the `EntryText` (it stays with the initial state of `"initial"`).

How can I have my TextField get updated when my ViewModel emits the string?

Comment: this : `val (text, setText) = remember { mutableStateOf(initialText) }` should be `val (text, setText) = remember(initialText) { mutableStateOf(initialText) }` - recalculate the lambda on key change.  However `EntryText` will never propogate `entry` text back to the viewmodel on user input text change making it one-way binding in the ui only and not saved on rotation I assume this is intentional?

Answer (score 1):

Because your text is handle by `ViewModel`, I think you can store it state in `ViewModel` like

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var entry = MutableStateFlow("initial")

    fun getEntryContent(): Flow<String> {
        // get from database
    }
}
```

In your `Activity`

```
val entry by viewModel.entry.collectAsState()

Column {
    Text(text = entry)

    EntryText(placeholder = hint, text = entry, onTextChanged = {
        viewModel.entry.value = it
    })
}

lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewModel.getEntryContent().flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle).collect {
        // observe value from db then set to TextField
        viewModel.entry.value = it
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Lihn. I had the same problem and although I was certain that the problem was the initial state inside the composable, I had not realised that by exposing a StateFlow instead of a Flow I can do the initialisation only once in my viewmodel